# How to add animation inside a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, core-animation, uicollectionviewcell, calayer

I'm attempting to add a circular loading animation inside of a UICollectionViewCell. I've added the exact same code to a normal UIViewController and it worked successfully but I don't get any results on a UICollectionViewCell.

Ideally I'd like to have the animation start when the cell becomes visible.

```
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()

func setupBezierPaths() {
    let center = self.center
    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 100, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)

    // Create a track layer
    trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    trackLayer.lineWidth = 10
    trackLayer.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.round
    trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

    layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)

    // Create a layer that is animated
    shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10
    shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0
    shapeLayer.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.round
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

    layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}
```

For the UICollectionViewCell, I'm not sure where to put the actual animation code. I've tried it inside the init but the track layer doesn't even show up. Here is the code for the animation:

```
    let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    basicAnimation.toValue = 1
    basicAnimation.duration = 1
    basicAnimation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
    basicAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    shapeLayer.add(basicAnimation, forKey: "simpleAnimation")
```

Comment: where do you add it?